# What should i add to the code to make run the while statement for password?

Tags: python

```
password = "joseph123"
x = str(input("Please enter your password: "))
if x == password:
 print("Hurray!!! your password is correct ")
elif x != password:
 print("Please try your password again ")
```

It only gives me the question to insert password once if the password is wrong and doesn't repeat to continue until the user gets it correctly
and also after putting the wrong password and then putting the right password it till shows wrong password

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: @jonrsharpe as much as I can see you're trying to help, how is the link relevant to the user's question?

Comment: hi @user22052524! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you familiar with `while` loops?

Comment: @Mark how is it not? That's the point where loops, which are what the OP refers to in the title and needs if it _"doesn't repeat to continue"_, are introduced.

Comment: oh right, they include a while loop in their example. 'First Steps Towards Programming' is a deceptive title

Comment: take a look at this OP, if you're not familiar! :-) https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while

Comment: Your question title suggests that you've heard of *while* loops. Did you consider trying to write one?

Comment: If you want to have a while statement, why don’t  you add a while statement?

Comment: Dear @user22052524 your question deals with the most basic concepts of programming languages. If you deal with this by trial and error, which is fine, then at least go look up available resources into which dozens of people have put in effort in order for others to learn. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `while` statement to continuously loop over the entries. That'd be:

```
password = "joseph123"
x = str(input("Please enter your password: "))

while x != password:
    # show error
    print('Please try your password again')
    x = str(input('Try again: '))

print('Hurray!!! your password is correct')
```

Comment: what is the use/need of the `else:`

Comment: no need for it. oops

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try a loop here, as the code is now it is going to stop after one pass through since there is only one iteration of the if statement. If you used something like `while x!= password` it might work better.